# Android Studio: Refactoring cannot be performed when importing images

Tags: macos, android-studio

All of a sudden this morning I am unable to drag png files into my drawable folders in Android Studio. I get the message "Refactoring cannot be performed - the file is read-only". I have confirmed that these files are not read only and have tried this with numerous image files in different locations on my Mac. Any ideas as to how this can be fixed please?

PS - This is occurring in all my Android Studio projects. I am running Android Studio 0.5.9 on OS X 10.9.3

Comment: I've got the same problem here..

Comment: This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70784

Comment: @ScottBarta Android Studio was updated this morning to 0.6.0. Not only did it break our projects as new SDK Build Tools had to be downloaded (and the Gradle build file manually updated), but the import issue noted above has not been fixed either. I am not implying you are responsible for any of those issues, but I do hope you can point out to the Android Studio dev team that the lack of care taken with updates reflects extremely poorly on Google.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I managed to solve it somehow. Just copy and paste the *.png you need in your drawable folder instead of dragging it. Turns out there's a problem with moving it

Later edit: holding ALT whilst dragging the files should also do the job. Thanks @RunLoop

Comment: I have also found that holding in alt whilst dragging works too.

Comment: @RunLoop that deserves an answer of its own imo.

Comment: @meda I ran into this just a view hours after you :)

Comment: @MennoGouw you were dragging the image too? lol thank Stackoverflow for saving us many wasted hours!!

Comment: I guess Google is not in a hurry to solve this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file you're attempting to add to, go to "Show in explorer" and then drag the files there. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Update to the most recent JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). The currently accepted answer by user DDsix worked for me, but that is a workaround. Updating the JDK will bring full functionality back.

I believe this is related to the following [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188774) on the AOSP bug tracker.