# Why does it keep say "Refactoring cannot be performed" when I copy a jar file into the lib folder in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

[image]

I'm trying to just copy an external library .jar file into my libs folder. It keeps saying, that it's a read-only file. How do I go about doing this? Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Refactoring cannot be performed when importing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052366/android-studio-refactoring-cannot-be-performed-when-importing-images)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't that your file is read only. It happened to me today on my iMac with *.png files that weren't read only. Instead of dragging it, try the old fashion way: copy your file and then paste it in your folder. It may work.
Apparently, it's a bug with the latest Android Studio

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. You pretty much nailed that problem for me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess that, if you're using Windows, you can also hold Alt while dragging and it would still do the job

Answer (score 3):

CTRL + Drag works for importing in Windows.

Comment: This helped, but what exactly is does CTRL+Drag do? I get a different type of window, is it more of a raw copy then a link orsomething? Some more details for understanding the mechanics is always welcome.

Comment: @Madmenyo it changes the default action of a drag n drop.  If you drag a file from one folder to another but stay within the same file system (disk or more accurately partition) then usually the file is moved, if you do it from one partition to another it is copied.  by holding down control the intra-partition drag becomes a copy (Im not 100% sure but I think the inter-partition drag becomes a move)   I am pretty sure of the within file system drag becoming a copy rather than move.  Sorry its been a long time since I used windows.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac you can hold down the Option key while dragging the files into Android Studio.

See the comment in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24053667/475217

Answer (score 0):

Go into properties for your .jar and uncheck Read Only.  Then switch over to the Android Development Bundle and never look back :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message gives you the reason. Your jar file is read-only and is not in your `libs` folder (right now it's in your `Downloads` folder).

Make sure you properly copy it to your libs folder, and try the re-factor again.